# CSS3 selector question for all but first select

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

With the following markup i want a CSS selector to select all but the first select menu within each options div - of which there may be many:

```html
<div class="options">
    <div class="opt1">
        <select title="Please choose Warranty">
            <option value="">Select Waranty</option>
            <option value="1">1 year guarantee</option>
            <option value="2">3 year guarantee</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="opt2">
        <select title="Please choose Color">
            <option value="">Select Color</option>
            <option value="1">Red</option>
            <option value="2">Blue</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="opt3">
        <select title="Please choose Size">
            <option value="">Select Size</option>
            <option value="1">Small</option>
            <option value="2">Big</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using this within Prototype which has almost full css3 selector support so not concerned by browser support.

The initial selector would be something like:

```
div.options div select
```

I've tried a few variations on `nth-child` and `:not(:first-child)` but can't seem to make it work.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

See: http://jsfiddle.net/uDvEt/1/

```
.options > div:not(:first-child) select { background:yellow;}
```

Answer (score 65):

You need to select the option `div`s instead of the `select`s when using `:not(:first-child)`, because every `select` is the first (and only) child of its parent `div`:

```
div.options > div:not(:first-child) > select
```

An alternative to `:not(:first-child)` is to use `:nth-child()` with a starting offset of 2, like this:

```
div.options > div:nth-child(n + 2) > select
```

Another alternative is with the general sibling combinator `~` (which is supported by IE7+):

```
div.options > div ~ div > select
```

Comment: thanks for the extra info, accepted the other answer as it was also correct and came through first.

Comment: Just in case you're concerned about older IEs, I've added a third solution.

Answer (score 1):

`.options > div:nth-child(n+2) select`

Answer (score -2):

.options > *:not(:first-child)

the best!